# Stop being topmost window

Tags: windows, winapi, window, topmost

My window should be on top of a specific "target" window that I don't have control over.

When the target window is activated, I call `SetWindowPos` with `HWND_TOPMOST` to place my window on top of it while the target can still be the active window.

When the target window is no longer the foreground window, I want my window to still be on top of the target window, but no longer topmost, so other windows are not covered by it.

Two ideas I had:

- Call `SetWindowPos` with `hWndInsertAfter` to be the just activated window. This fails when the just activated window is topmost, because my window then does not lose the topmost status. Another issue with this: If the just activated window is the desktop, then my window is placed below the target window.
- Call `SetWindowPos` with `HWND_NOTOPMOST` to lose the topmost status. However, this brings my window to the top of all non-topmost windows, so it covers the just activated window. To fix this I have to bring the just activated window on top again with another `SetWindowPos` with `HWND_TOP`. This feels like the wrong way to do it and may cause flicker.

Is it possible to have a window just stop being topmost and placing it below the current foreground window?

Comment: Topmost means on top of all other Windows that are not marked as Topmost. So if no other Window is marked topmost, your Window will be topmost. Why not create a Modal Dialog? It will be topmost for your appication only.

Comment: @GaneshR. As said I don't have control over the target window. The target window also should be active while my window is on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only automatic method to make a window permanently on top of another one whether the target window is top-most or not is an owner/owned relationship. You could **try** using `SetParent` to create this relationship but note that [Raymond Chen does say it's not recommended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx).

Assuming you're tracking window activations somehow, I think your `SetWindowPos` idea (the first one) is the way to do it, with the following modification:

- When the target window is active, set your window to `HWND_TOPMOST`
- When the target loses activation, insert your window after the **target** window's immediate predecessor in the z-order (i.e. effectively still on top of the target window, but not top-most)

Something like this psuedo-code:

```
if (foregroundwindow == targetwindow)
   SetWindowPos(my_window, HWND_TOPMOST, ...);
else
{
    HWND hwndPred = GetWindow(targetwindow, GW_HWNDPREV);
    if (!hwndPred)
    {
        // no predecessor so my_window will still be on top, just not top-most any more
        if (GetWindowLong(targetwindow, GWL_EXSTYLE) & WS_EX_TOPMOST)
            hwndPred = HWND_NOTOPMOST;
    }
    SetWindowPos(my_window, hwndPred, ...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really well. Also covers the case when two windows suddenly would go to the top of the z order. In my approaches my window would be between those two.